# Geometric progression in mips with recursive function

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips, mips32

I am trying to write a program in Assembly Mips that does the following:

> I have to use the math formula of geometric progression G(n)=A*omega^n

In C this would be :

```
int geometr(int n)
{
    if(n==0) return A;
    else return omega*geom(n-1);
}
```

I know that I have to use the Stack but I am kind of new in Assembly Language so I don't know how to make the recursion right. I have studied other questions about recursion but they weren't.

Comment: what did you find when you compiled this function?

Comment: there is nothing special or magic about recursion you simply implement the function.

Comment: If you have trouble with a recursive implementation then I would suggest starting by translating the C reference code into an iterative (and compiling) implementation instead.